# MBean metric collection in weblogic is disabled for some Types

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, metrics, diagnostics

I am trying to Monitor some metrics on Weblogic, but some of them are shown as disabled in the list of Types present in the admin console (/console/dashboard).
What does this mean?
Can I not monitor these Metrics using a Diagnostic Module?
Or Is there a way somewhere to enable these Types back on?

I did a good share of googling, nothing turned up.

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24401_02/taskhelp/diagnostics/EnableOrDisableMetricCollectionInADiagnosticModule.html ?

Comment: Yes I have, it doesn't work if there are no detected instances for the Bean, although I am not sure what are "instances" in this context.